# Only change the extension of an url, keep query-string

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have a search form, that uses get-parameters to determine what is searched and I want to have the search results as rss-feed.

So I'm using the route rss-extension to have those available and want to generate a link to the rss feed for that search/query.

`$this->Html->link(__("Search results as rss"), ['ext' => 'rss']);` leaves out all the params and I haven't found a way to extract the get-params in a sane way.
Is there some shortcut to just use the actual current url and change the extension?

The best way I found so far was:
`$this->Html->link(__("Search results"), ['ext' => 'rss', '?' => $this->passedArgs]);`
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you might want to use

```
'?' => $this->request->query
```

Then it only uses the query strings - which is what you want after all.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I use, dont know if `$this->link` work the same way:

```
$url = $this->params['url'];

echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'url' => array(
    'action' => 'yourAction',
    '?' => $url,
    'ext' => 'rss'
    )
));
echo $this->Form->end('Search Results');
```

Comment: It seems to have the same effect, but as mine or `$this->request->query`, but it doesn't seem as clear as the other suggestion.